# Why is it ordained that Shudras should serve the Dvijas, and especially Brahmanas, as their foremost duty?

Tags: caste-system, shudra

Why is it ordained that Shudras must serve the Dvijas, and especially Brahmanas, as their foremost duty?

Does this oppress Shudras or is it actually beneficial for them to serve the twice-born?

Comment: Interpolation by Vedantins

Comment: @RakeshJoshi The Vedas say the same thing, same thing with all Dharma Shastras, all Puranas, Mahabharata, and Ramayana. Are all Hindu scriptures interpolated by Vedantins? On the contrary, Vedanta IS Hinduism.

Comment: then quote them. Why making claims with no.backup ?

Comment: @RakeshJoshi I just quoted a Mahabharata verse in my answer below.

Comment: you mentioned five plus categories of shastras . and also it would be better if you can quote from Vedas

Comment: @RakeshJoshi Here is one from the Manusmriti: "For the Śūdra the highest duty conducive to his best welfare is to attend upon such Brāhmaṇa house-holders as are learned in the Vedas and famous.—(9.334)" And from the Taittiriya Samhita (7.1.1): "Therefore.... the Sudras, are dependent on others."

Comment: do proper research on manu smriti. It was never a law book.

Comment: @RakeshJoshi Says who?

Comment: prove it that it was used in mainstream society

Comment: @RakeshJoshi https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/32288/11726

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does this oppress Shudras or is it actually beneficial for them to serve the twice-born?

**It does not oppress Shudras, but instead, is actually beneficial for them to serve the twice-born.**

In fact, the quality of Tamas oppresses Shudras, as explained by this Mahabharata verse:

> Mahābhārata—Anuśāsana (Do.).—‘Finding the Śūdra oppressed with bad
>   traits due to the quality of Tamas, Pitāmaha ordained attendance upon
>   the twice-born as his duty. Through his devotion to the twice-born,
>   the Śūdra drops off all those traits due to the quality of Tamas; and
>   by attending upon the twice-born, the Śūdra attains the highest
>   good.—Harmless, devoted to good deeds, worshipful towards gods and the
>   twice-born, the Śūdra becomes endowed with all the rewards of Dharma.’

So serving Dvijas actually makes Shudras sattvic. Hence, it is beneficial for them and not oppressive.

Comment: whenever we advice someone to do something they don't like, and also add 'i'm telling it for your own good'.. what would their reaction be ? :)

Comment: Whats need to become sattvik? Which Veda says so ?

Comment: @RakeshJoshi Because according to Gita and Manusmriti, sattva quality helps one do good actions.

Comment: @Ikshvaku who follows manu smriti? And geeta also says that vedas are.nothing but matter of tri gunas so one must overcome them. And vedas are flowery words one must not get attracted to them. I am happy to adopt Vedas than geetA

Comment: @RakeshJoshi The "flowery words" thing is referring to the karma kanda.

Comment: @Ikshvaku so you will do nindaa of karma kanda !!! Then accept that geeta has veda droha verses

Comment: @RakeshJoshi What the Bhagavad Gita criticizes is not the Karma Kanda of the Vedas, but people who focus on the Karma Kanda of the Vedas to the exclusion of the Jnana Kanda, i.e. Mimamsakas.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan jnana kaanda or mimamsa is not even mentioned in the verse. Prove it please.

Comment: All the avataras also did this karma kanda. No scope that it can be bad or wrong.

Comment: Sir Sudras nourish Earth says Brihandyak Upanishad. Without Sudra society will collapse. Vidur,Sanjay,Dharmavyad,Nammalvar,Kanak Dasa,Dhanurdasa, all are Sudras and respected a lot and even worshipped. Sudras indeed lived a happy life free from restrictions. They are most fortunate in this age and can get Moksha easily.But isn't it unjust to say about Manu 2.31?Please see it!!Manu says for Sudras to keep names matching despicable,vile,low,mean, base pitiful,abject,worthless,paltry,sorry 

Comment: @SethuSrivatsaKoduru It doesn't mean offensive names like that. It means names indicating their profession or status in society. One example given by a commentator is the name "naradAsa", which means "servant of man". So names like that. Carpenter names are also suitable. Western countries also follow same naming custom. For example, you have last names like "shoemaker", "butler", "smith", etc. which indicate labouring jobs.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Ikshvaku Sir!

Comment: @SethuSrivatsaKoduru Glad to be of help.